# Safe SEF URL to a subdomain

Tags: joomla-3.x, url, joomla-3.6, sef

I have a multi site comprising a main J! installation and two secondaries J! installations.

The last twos are installed in the same `root` directory of the main one, as following

J1: administrator, components, plugins, ..., J2, J3

If I make a link in J1 pointing to a page in J2, the URL in the bar doesn't show in a SEF format. I'm using **Joomla 3.6.2**.

Could anyone point me to a possible source of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean with the Multi-sites but 3 installations for 3 sites isn't considered a multi-sites scenario. Probably you have 1 Joomla website installed on the root of your hosting account and 2 more in subfolders.

You haven't specified the conditions and how you are trying to link from the main site to the other 2, what's the purpose and how the links are generated and what is it if any the relationship of the linked sites/pages.

But from what it seems, this is an external link from one website to another. You are leaving Main Joomla to go to another Joomla.

If your link is of **Non-SEF** format, then when you reach to the other websites the url will still be a **Non-SEF** one, unless you have any redirections from the Non-SEF to the corresponding SEF one.

So, if you link like this:

```
/myJoomla2Site/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=123&Itemid=123
```

That's exactly the URL you will end up on the other website.

**[sh404SEF](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/sh404sef)** (paid extension) could help as it auto-creates and auto-redirects all **non-SEF URLs** to their **SEF** versions. Note that **sh404SEF** has to be installed on those sites that the Non-SEF should turn the SEF one - therefore on the site that you are linking to.

You could also use the J! core **Redirect component** to manually make redirections - or redirect using the `.htaccess` in the same fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are 2 ways.

sub.domain.com or domain.com/sub.
If they are not content related and have secondary home pages per install. Then method is good.

I usually use the second and name that folder in an SEO friendly. But that is because the sites are related.

Other than that, more needs to be explained and/or some URL results and what methods you tried already.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Maybe my question it wasn't clear. I already have the multisite in a form: domain.com, domain.com/sub1, domain.com/sub2. Now, if I go (through a link) from domain.com to domain.com/sub1 what I see in the browser bar is domain.com/sub1/index.php?option=com_mycomponent.... What I'd like to see is domain.com/sub1/mycooladdress, as defined in my router file. What it seems to me is that going from domain to subdomain the router file in my component is ignored.

Comment: All 3 sites have have SEF friendly URLS and Rewriting on, with the htaccess.txt changed to .htaccess and it is on an apache server?

Comment: Yes, these are the settings for all the three sites. Each internal link (from domain to domain, or sub to sub) behaves correctly and the urls are SEF friendly. The problem arises only between domain -> subdomain.

Comment: Do you actually have domain names pointing to the subfolders? When I use my above method, I do not use a separate domain name. I use it as such mainsite.com/subfolder-name and my URL are good.

Comment: What do you mean with domain names pointing to the subfolders?

Comment: Do you have 3 domains or are you attempting to just point to a subfolder name, through one domain name?

Comment: Through the main domain (main Joomla installation) I'm trying to point to a subdomain (second Joomla installation), which is a subfolder of the main installation.

Comment: Assuming you have done everything else correctly you can try this method: You will have to edit the .htaccess file and find the following line:

# RewriteBase /

Remove the “#” from the line and if you have installed your joomla site in a sub-folder (ie: http://yoursite.com/joomla ), insert the sub-folder name after the “/”

RewriteBase /joomla

If joomla is installed in the root folder, you don’t need to add any sub directory to the code, just use it like this:

RewriteBase /

Now check your site and see the effects of the changes.